# join query for 2 tables in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have two table in database like following

**table 1 : playlist**

```
id    name    user_id
1     test1    3
2     test2    4
3     test3    3
```

**table 2 : playlist_shared**

```
id    playlist_id    user_id
1     1              6
2     1              3
3     2              3
```

now i want to select `unique id` and `name` of playlist from playlist table where `user_id=3` in both table.

**output will be**

```
 id    name
 1     test1
 2     test2
 3     test3
```

please help me to short out this.

Comment: `select id,name from playlist ` this will give you a expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id,name from playlist where user_id = 3
union
select p.id id, name 
     from (select * from playlist_shared where user_id=3) ps join playlist p 
     on p.id = ps.playlist_id
```